# What can I replace my garden with?

Tags: cold-weather, desert, hot-weather

I'm in a situation where its a waste of time, effort and money to take care of our many little gardens (Different separate gardens ranging between 20-90 meters square). Briefly, we rarely visit them and its is nearly impossible to be available to take care of them the whole year. We could be available only a few weeks a year !!!

Also we don't have access to good water. But we can use underground water which is very bad for the grass so we mainly use for other purposes. It's a rainy area during winter.

Basically these gardens are in coastal-desert areas so in summer its extremely hot and dry during day and very nice during night and in winter its extremely cold during night and very nice during day.

I'm mentioning these conditions because I'm looking to replace these gardens with something that could be useful or at least not harmful to cope with during very hot and dry conditions or very cold conditions.

Hopefully I was clear enough. Thank you for your time.

Comment: what part of the world do you live in? Do you have a budget for this? Are the gardens accessible: ie can you bring in soil,plants etc?

Comment: I'm in Egypt, Sinai. Yes the gardens are accessible. I don't have a specific budget as I'm still studying my options.

Comment: Are you looking for something ornamental? I'm assuming the gardens have been planted with edibles before? What are the low wintertime temps, and the average summer rainfall?

Comment: I've been working on a way to answer this type of question, impossible without an awful lot of back and forth and information gathering.  Trying to get a format that would be useful as we do have Landscaping in our title...sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are going for a low-maintenance garden that will not require humans to be there to care for them, I think your best bet is to go with a native plant garden. It will need care while you are establishing it, but once the plants have developed a strong root system, they will require almost no care.

Have you seen the Project Noah? There is a page on Native Flora and Fauna of the Sinai. It might give you some ideas of plants you could use:
https://www.projectnoah.org/missions/11481015

Another resource that might be helpful is the Royal Botanic Garden of Jordan. They're doing really interesting work in habitat recreation. When I look on their website, they are currently really focused on the forest habitats which occur in Northern and Eastern Jordan, but they do mention the acacia and sand dune habitats that occur in the south of Jordan near Aqaba and may be close to your native habitat, depending on where exactly you live. You might be able to get more information from them on appropriate plants to use:
http://royalbotanicgarden.org/page/investing-people